# 2 wire 6 AWG Aluminum wire used for a 4 prong dryer outlet

Tags: dryer, aluminum

I am pretty comfortable and knowledgeable with wiring and basic electricity however I am stumped with how to proceed with my current problem. My dryer died and needed a new dryer cord (it is 4 prong dryer cord) and when I went to plug in my new cord I noticed a chip in the outlet. Easy enough to change out. I turned off the power and unscrewed the old plug and then I noticed a problem. The wire being used is a 3CDRS Size 6 AWG Aluminum wire.

What are my options on proceeding? Do I proceed in connecting the old wire to the new plug like how it was (not sure if it is allowed by code). Do I need to hire an electrician to redo the whole aluminum wire?

[image]

Comment: Someone cheated.  The best option is to replace that cable with a /3 plus ground, two hots, a neutral, and a ground.  The second best is to add a ground wire to that circuit, but will need to insulate the bare neutral from that box.

Comment: That, or use a two-pole GFCI breaker and mark this outlet "GFCI protected - no equipment ground." (still need to isolate the neutral from the boxes at both ends, assuming that's a legit "bare neutral" cable - if it's not, you have to replace it.)

Comment: I was thinking I may need to replace the whole thing with /3 wire, however I was hoping there would be an easier or better way without ripping it out. I see something about Polaris Connectors, could I use those to connect to a /3 copper wire and then run the copper wire to the 4 Pole outlet like it was supposed to be?

Comment: Is it an option to simply use the AlumiConn connectors in a junction box to connect to 8 /3 or 10 /3 AWG wire and then run those to the 4 prong receptacle?

Comment: Since this question was functionally re-asked [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/274883/what-is-are-the-supply-current-of-the-wires-in-a-6-awg-aluminum-wire/274901#274901), and no answers exist here, I'm closing this one as a dup. OP you could help tidy up by going one step further and selecting "Delete" on the words just below the keywords.

Comment: Note this is not an exact duplicate of my other question. The other one I asked what each of the wires are. This is my main question as to what to do to be up to code. People started posting solutions on the other one. I could have main it one question but there really are 2.