# What is/are the supply (current?) of the wires in a #6 AWG Aluminum wire?

Tags: dryer

[image]In the picture, what are 3 wires? I believe the red/black on the right and all black on left are the positive wire, but is the center wire neutral or ground? There is no apparent consensus on other answers if the extra wire is neutral or ground.[image]

Comment: Can you post a photo of the front of the receptacle please?

Comment: As noted in comments on your previous question using the same picture, ( https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/274678/18078 ) it can depend on the type of the gray jacketed cable. Some cables that look like that have a bare conductor that can be neutral. Others do not. You need to share the writing on the cable jacket to know what this cable is, which affects whether you can simply retrofit a ground wire, or if you need to replace the whole cable. Also, there's no "postive" wire here. Household electric supply is alternating current, not direct current.

Comment: Thanks for the info Ecnerwal. Then the appropriate would be current on both black wires, but is the bare neutral or ground.

Comment: Just a note, I am trying to understand the bare wire to see what options I really have to replace this or just put a 3 prong dryer outlet in and address this at a later date.

Comment: You really only have two options.  The best one is to replace that cable with the proper one.  The second best is to run a separate ground wire and tape/insulate that bare wire from the box.  As that is a neutral(for dryer) the tape/insulating covering should be white or grey.  I do not think it is allowed in code to change a four prong outlet back to a NEMA 10 outlet/plug, not saying what you have now is in code either.

Comment: For the ground wire, would that be connected to a standard outlet? I see a lot of 3 Prong to 4 Prong wire extensions that have a green wire that plugs into standard outlet. What if I connected a green ground wire from the outlet box to this for the 4th ground wire?

Comment: You have to go to where there is ground.  From that box to probably to the panel. will need 10 gauge wire for a normal 30 amp dryer.  Most of those 3 to 4 prong adapters are for heaters/welders that do not need neutral, so the neutral wire is not connected at all.

Comment: @ConsultingMechanic 250.130(C) specifies the manner in which you may retrofit ground. TLDR: take #10 bare or green wire to anywhere else that has #10 or larger wire going back to the panel (non-flex metal conduit shell counts as #10 wire).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can depend on what it is used on.

For circuits like dryers that use both 240v and 120v that bare wire is used as neutral.  The circuits used NEMA 10(hot, hot, and neutral) type plugs and receptacles, but were banned in 1996 for new circuits for being unsafe.

For circuits that only use 240v like heaters, welders, that bare wire can be used as ground. You would use NEMA 6(hot, hot, and ground) plugs and receptacles.

The plug in the picture looks like a NEMA 14(hot, hot, neutral, and ground) type.  If it uses four prongs, then that plug should be used with a /3 cable plus ground, two hots, an insulated/covered neutral wire and a bare ground wire.

Someone cheated to make it look safe, but that cable should be changed to keep you safe, that dryer probably has no ground at all at that receptacle.

Answer (score 4):

### This work is illegal

If you are straining to believe the wiring as-found is legal or safe, that would be why this is confusing.  This is *not good* (asterisk: unless it was fed from a GFCI breaker). Not the worst imaginable miswiring, but hardly proper nor legal.

This feeds a dryer or range.  Those need neutral for their 120V parts.  Due to a foolish concession in 1966, many dryers/ranges were wired with 3-wire connections and 3-wire sockets as late as 1997. They are all dangerous, and we know that now.

Here we see a 4-wire socket but with a 3-wire supply.  That is illegal on its face (since it promises ground but has none)... but can be OK in either of two cases, provided the bare neutral has been carefully insulated to avoid contact with the metal box.

- The Retrofit Ground rules (NEC 250.130) have been used to retrofit a #10 ground wire to place that has #10 or larger back to the panel, e.g. water heater junction box.
- The breaker in the panel is GFCI, and the socket is marked "GFCI Protected / No Equipment Ground" per 406.4(D).

406.4(D) specifies the rules for replacing a receptacle in-kind.  I know you could continue this in service and just "take a pass" on replacing the receptacle, but this is a plain defect that could hurt your family.

### This is [SEU cable, or Service Entrance-Unarmored cable](https://www.wireandcableyourway.com/ser-service-entrance-cable-aluminum).

The *Service Entrance* is the wiring from the top of the weatherhead, through the meter pan, to your main breaker. **Ground does not exist in the Service Entrance** because it hasn't been established yet - that happens at the main breaker.

Thus, the bare wire in SEU *is intended as* neutral.  However, Code 338.10(B)(2) allows* you to abandon its use as neutral and use it as a ground instead, which is handy.  The problem with that on a dryer circuit is, what do you do for neutral?

Because this is a legacy installation, you may continue its use as a neutral, and retrofit a ground per 250.130(C).   It is not possible to retrofit a neutral.

### And as far as retrofitting ground

You need to ground to the ground screw in the metal box, and you're done. The box will carry ground to the receptacle.   So here is your punch list:

- Shrink tube or sleeve or tape wrap to isolate the neutral mesh from the metal box
- #10-32 thread short screw to use in the tapped hole in the box for ground
- #10 bare or green wire run back to somewhere with a ground that big back to the panel.  You need to go back to the panel itself, or any junction box with #10 ground back to the panel, or any junction box with non-flex metal conduit back to the panel, or the Grounding Electrode Conductor (copper wire between panel and ground rods).  No water pipes!

---

---

---

* although almost any use of SEU in a **new** circuit or feeder will entail using the neutral as ground, because ground is required and retrofitting ground isn't allowed in new work.

Comment: I know this is illegal. I am trying to figure out what each of the wires so i can then figure out what my options are. I know removing and rewiring this is the best option, but i do not have the money to do this now.
Thank you for providing the NEC codes, I was having a hard time finding what pertains to my situation.

Comment: @ConsultingMechanic If you have confidence in the 3 conductors you have, I would not advise rewiring. Retrofitting ground is sufficient, and easy depending on available route.

Answer (score 2):

Without seeing the front of the outlet, it's almost impossible to tell and even then, might not be able to tell because the dryer wiring has been screwed up for years with different plugs and outlets and DIYer improvising to get their dryers to work. The best way to tell would be to go back to the main panel and see where the cable is terminated. If you have a sub panel, the neutral bus and grounding bus should be separated so you can tell what the wire is by which bus it's connected to. If it's your main panel neutrals and ground can share the same bus so you won't be able to tell. The two black wires in your picture are the hot wires. you can verify that in th panel too. A new dryer hookup should have four wires, two hots, a neutral and a ground so if you're rewiring, fix this.

Comment: The front is the standard 4 prong receptacle for a dryer. It has a nick at the top so to be safe i was going to replace it, but that opened a can of worms that you see above. I am trying to understand what I have here so I can see what my options are (as i asked in the other question).

Comment: If that wire is a neutral, you'll have 240V between the two hot and 120V between a hot and the neutral.  If that wire is a ground, then you're lmited to a 240V device.